# What was the (unofficial) Minecraft Snapshot 20w14✨?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I remember seeing many videos about a community "20w14✨" update but I didn't know what it was.
After searching for a while, I found it here: https://minecraft.plagiatus.net/article/minecraft-snapshot-20w14%e2%9c%a8/

What was the project about? Who made it? I can't find any much information anymore.

(this is an unofficial snapshot. Not to be confused with the 20w14∞ update.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's from the old Verified Helpers team on the Minecraft Commands discord (link found on /r/MinecraftCommands)

> The Verified Helpers of this server joined together to create a data pack and resource pack for April Fools Day!  It was intended to be a fake snapshot, hence the name "20w14✨" and the joke snapshot page here:
> https://minecraft.plagiatus.net/article/minecraft-snapshot-20w14s/
> You can download the creation from the link above or from github here (https://github.com/MinecraftCommands/20w14s), though the public servers are no longer maintained.

Credits: Arcensoth, Bahlph, Elli, Ersatz, Maxaxik, PeerHeer, Plagiatus, SirBenet, Sprunkles, the der discohund, Yurihaia

Comment: I'd like a bitcoin pickaxe for bitcoin mining.

Comment: Well you're in luck!